# How do run my script inside tmux on server startup

Tags: tmux

I have a bot which I run inside tmux session to keep it alive always. Sometimes, I server reboots and if I am not home or with the internet, my bot remains offline.
I can add a cron job to start the bot. I have a script like this

```
tmux new -s bot
bash '/home/user/bot_start.sh'
```

but what it does is that it starts a new tmux session but runs

```
bot_start.sh
```

outside of tmux session.
I want it to run that script inside the tmux session it opens up i.e., "bot"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tmux` command takes the command that it should execute within the session as an argument on the command line.  If no argument is given, an interactive shell is started.  Once the command (or the shell) terminates, the `tmux` session exits too.

Therefore, you could use

```
tmux new-session -s bot bash "$HOME/bot_start.sh"
```

This would start a new `tmux` session and run the given script in it.

To test whether there is already a session and avoid starting a new one if there is:

```
! tmux has-session -t bot 2>/dev/null && tmux new-session -s bot bash "$HOME/bot_start.sh"
```

or, more verbosely,

```
if ! tmux has-session -t bot 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux new-session -s bot bash "$HOME/bot_start.sh"
fi
```

Comment: Can I run my commands instead of executing the script?
like this
cd ~/bot && python3 app.py
if it is possible, then what would be the of doing it?

Comment: @AliHasan Well, you could do `cd ~/bot && tmux new -s bot python3 app.py`, sure.